# How to get element from inner DOM.(DOM with-in DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom

### Overview:

I am attempting to get an element by id. The problem I am running into is working with a complex DOM. I understand I can get a element by id.
`document.getElementById('#some-id')`

The DOM that I am working with seems to have an two inner `DOMs`. My question is how do I get an ID from an inner `DOM`. I have attached a screen shot as shown below to demostrate what I am working with as you can see from the screen shot there are two document objects and the root document object is what I am currently receiving when printing out the contents of the `document` object.

### Question:

How do you get an element that exists embedded within another `DOM`.

### Screen Shot:

[image: elements]

### Example:

```
<!--Root DOM-->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Creates dom object-->
    <iframe id="i1" src="iframe1.html">
        <!--Creates dom object-->
        <iframe id="i2" src="iframe2.html">
            <!--How do you access this element by id.-->
            <div id="flyover">
                innerHtml
            </div>
        </iframe>
    </iframe>
```

Comment: Please include code, not images of code.

Comment: @jhpratt The code is a bit long to post as a whole piece. I feel like chunks will make the questions more difficult to understand than what I am asking. None the less I will add the chunks of code and explain.

Comment: You should post a [mcve]. We likely don't need to see everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you're correct - the `iframe` will host its own DOM.

You have to traverse the outer DOMs into the sub-frame you're attempting to perform operations on:

```
window.frames[0].frames[0].document.getElementById("flyout");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding an `id` to your `iframe`, than use:

```
document.getElementById( /* your ID */ ).contentWindow.document.getElementById("flyout");
```

Comment: Is the 'your-id' the id of the element that contains what is being searched for? So for example the root?

Comment: The 'your id' is the ID you should add to the iframe so you can uniquely identify it.